# Android: ayncTask tried to update the progress bar in orientation changed

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-orientation

I have two layouts for orientation: `portrait layout` and `landscape layout`. In the portrait layout, I used the progress bar and download the files. I used `AsyncTask` and updated the progress bar in the `onPostExecute()` method. When I change the landscape orientation, the system will replace with landscape layout. My problem is that when I change the landscape orientation during the downloading files, I got the `NullPointerException` for progress bar. Because `AsyncTask` tried to update the progress bar after downloading files. I have two questions for that.

1. I have no idea how to skip the updating this progress bar.
2. And when the orientation change back to portrait during downloading, I want to show the progress bar status.

**EDIT**

```
         @Override
         protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
           int count = values[0];
           loadingBar.setProgress(count);
           progressTxt.setText(count +"/" + listSize);          

         }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            loadingBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            loadingBarLbl.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

                loadingBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                undefinedloadingBarLbl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you have configChanges="orientation" in your manifest?

Comment: add config changes to your manifest file dude